# Problem when using Hector0.8.0 do addCounter

Tags: cassandra, hector

I'm using hector-core 0.8.0-1 and Cassandra 0.8.0 to test a addCounter operation, but I found my code cannot insert any data into the CF, can anyone tell me the reason?

```
StringSerializer ser = StringSerializer.get();
Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, ser);

List<HCounterColumn<String>> counterColumns = Arrays.asList(
        HFactory.createCounterColumn("1", 30L, ser),
        HFactory.createCounterColumn("2", 20L, ser)
        );  

for (HCounterColumn c : counterColumns)
{   
    mutator.addCounter("testKey1", "CounterColumn", c); 
    mutator.addCounter("testKey2", "CounterColumn", c); 
}   

mutator.execute();
```

and I found the following info in my log:

```
> 2011-06-21 17:17:00,025 [Thread-3]
> INFO me.prettyprint.cassandra.hector.TimingLogger
> - Tag                                       Avg(ms) 
>      Min      Max  Std Dev     95th   Count 2011-06-21 17:17:00,030
> [Thread-3] INFO me.prettyprint.cassandra.hector.TimingLogger
> - WRITE.fail_                                  4.84 
>     4.84     4.84     0.00     4.84       1 2011-06-21 17:17:00,031 [Thread-3]
> INFO me.prettyprint.cassandra.hector.TimingLogger
> - META_WRITE.fail_                            17.20 
>    11.31    23.09     5.89    23.09       2 2011-06-21 17:17:00,031 [Thread-3]
> INFO me.prettyprint.cassandra.hector.TimingLogger
> -
```

seems something wrong while doing mutator.execute();

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the CF specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
cfDef.setDefaultValidationClass(...)
```

This is available in the latest version of trunk, 0.7.0  and 0.8.0 branch.

So you need to pull from sources.

or, if you want to do that, and assoming you are using the latest hector available at maven central, you can do this

```
ThriftCfDef cfDef = new ThriftCfDef(String keyspace, String   columnFamilyName, ComparatorType comparatorType)

cf.setDefaultValidationClass(ComparatorType.COUNTERTYPE.getClassName());

cluster.addColumnFamiily(cfDef);
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently, in Cassandra 0.8.0, you cannot create counter columns in a Column Family that is not specifically created to handle counters:

```
create column family Counter1 with default_validation_class = CounterColumnType;
```

Here is the JIRA reference:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2614

Comment: Thanks sdolgy, but I check hector's source code and found I cannot define a columnfamily with a CounterColumnType validation class. I have found some code like 

`columnDefinition.setValidationClass(ComparatorType.LONGTYPE.getClassName());`
 


in order to set attributes for column, but hector0.8.0's ComparatorType does not have org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CounterColumnType here.

Comment: Are you able to create the CF first through the command line?    Alternately, check out this link:  https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/Getting-started-%285-minutes%29  "ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef" is what you want to look at.  You don't need to set each column with the validation ... just set the default.

Comment: Thanks @sdolgy, actually I created the CF by using  
   
`ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef1 = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition("Keyspace1", "Counter2");
cluster.addColumnFamily(cfDef1);`
  
and I changed its validation_class by cassandra-cli(if not, there will be WRITE.fail_), I'm just wondering whether there is an hector api to do this change ...

Comment: i don't believe so.  may have better luck on the hector mailing list for that question...or create a new question on here about how to modify an existing column family using the Hector library

Comment: seems hector really don't provide that for now, I found [http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.hector.user/3358] here said so. I also greped the code.. 
`grep "CounterColumnType" -R .`

Comment: Suffice to say, I think my answer is sufficient for the question

Comment: Teng Teng, you should be able to update the validation class through Hector. ColumnFamilyDefinition.setDefaultValidationClass(...) is the way.

Comment: From reading the JIRA issue, it also means that you can't mix regular columns in with counter columns; that's too bad as it means now I need 2 Column Families with the same set of keys.